# How to Fill Arrays Without Overwriting

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create and fill a new array from an already given array. But when I try to do this with for loop and array=i; the array just gives out the last value of the original array.

```
void evensOdds(){


int xs[18]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,555,558,333};
int Odd = 0;
int Even = 0;

// Counts the odds and evens in the array.
for (int i=0; i<18; i++){

    if (xs[i]%2 == 0) {
        Even++;
        }
    else {
        Odd++;
        }
}

// Defines the odd - even arrays.
const int NEven = Even;
const int NOdd = Odd;
int odd_xs[NOdd];
int even_xs[NEven];

// Fills the arrays with proper values.
for (int i=0; i<18; i++){

    if (xs[i]%2 == 0) {
        even_xs[NEven]= xs[i];
        }
    else {
        odd_xs[NOdd]= xs[i];
        }
}  

std::cout<<"Number of odds in the array:  "<<Odd<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Number of evens in the array:  "<<Even<<std::endl;

std::cout<<"Odd numbers are= "<<odd_xs[NOdd]<<std::endl;
std::cout<<"Even numbers are= "<<even_xs[NEven]<<std::endl;

return;
}
```

So the output of this code's cout line is

```
odd_xs array = 55
even_xs array = 66
```

Whereas it should've been something like

```
odd_xs array = 1, 11, 15, 55
even_xs array = 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 66
```

How can I do this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: First of all: format your code properly (I've done it for you) so it is readable, It's hard to work with unreadable code, even for experts. BTW the code you posted doesn't output anything. [Edit] and post a [mcve] and take care of correct code formatting while doing so

Comment: The problem seems to be with what exactly NOdd and NEven are in your code. So please provide a [mre]. You can also make sure that it demonstrates your observation. Consider writing the MRE so that it outputs "the array just gives out the last value of the original array" and describe what output you expect instead.

Comment: Maybe, you just want [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition).

Comment: I've added the complete code to see what are the variables exactly are.

Comment: `const int NOdd = Odd; int odd_xs[NOdd];` is invalid C++ (that use VLA extension). use `std::vector` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is rather C than C++.

This is one idiomatic way in C++, using appropriate standard C++ classes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

void evensOdds() {
  int xs[] = { 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,555,558,333 };

  std::vector<int> odd_xs;
  std::vector<int> even_xs;

  for (auto value : xs) {

    if (value % 2 == 0) {
      even_xs.push_back(value);
    }
    else {
      odd_xs.push_back(value);
    }
  }

  std::cout << "Number of odds in the array:  " << odd_xs.size() << std::endl;
  std::cout << "Number of evens in the array:  " << even_xs.size() << std::endl;

  std::cout << "Odd numbers are = "; 

  for (auto value : odd_xs)
    std::cout << value << " ";

  std::cout << "\n";

  std::cout << "Even numbers are = ";
  for (auto value : even_xs)
    std::cout << value << " ";

  std::cout << "\n";

  return;
}

int main()
{
  evensOdds();
}
```

Comment: *"This is the idiomatic way in C++"*. the -> one :). [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition), [`std::filter_view`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/filter_view) are other alternative

Answer (score 0):

You always write to `even_xs[NEven]` for example, so the value will always be overwritten and at the end only one value will be stored in `even_xs[NEven]`

Generally there is not enough code provided, for example you would need a loop to print out every element of your array, but we can't see if you are using a loop or just a single `cout` statement for printing

Comment: I've added the complete code, I print out at the end without any loops

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to put even values in `xs` into the `even_xs` array and the odd ones into the `odd_xs` array, you probably want something like this:

```
NEven = 0;
NOdd = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < 18; i++) {
  if (xs[i] % 2 == 0) {
    even_xs[NEven++] = xs[i];    
  }
  else {
    odd_xs[NOdd++] = xs[i];
  }
}
```

BTW: this code is actually rather C code, in C++ you would do this differently.

Comment: When I make the corrections you offered the output is odd=145813328 and even=145807056 .  I've added the complete code maybe there's something  I failed to mention in the first code I asked.

Comment: `std::cout << "Odd numbers are= " << odd_xs[NOdd] << std::endl;` is wrong, it ouputs only the element `NOdd` of `odd_xs`, but the last element of this array os `odd_xs[nOdd - 1]`. You need a loop and print each element of the array individually.